# DateTime when user starts to track location in Android

Tags: android, datetime, geolocation, tracking

I'm writing a mobile app and I need Android to store in a variable and send to a remote server the datetime when the user pressed the button to start tracking its location.

What I'm doing right now is `String date = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this).toString().concat(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this).toString());` but of course it doesn't work, as it inserts this in the remote DB `java.text.SimpleDateFormat@387875cajava.text.Simpl...`

I'm doing the same thing for the calls and SMS data, but in this case I'm querying the content resolver and getting the date from there, but for the location I'm a little bit stuck..

Thanks a lot in advance for the replies.

Best,
Manuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you prefer working with UTC time converted to long.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long utcTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings();
```

Comment: perfect! as I realized that in the other tables I have, I'm also using the UTC time, from the Content Providers. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

DateFormat is used for formatting or parsing a date. I think the `format(..)` method can help you:

```
String myFormattedDate = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this).format(new Date());
```

The actual time is received by the Date class. DateFormat is only used for formatting the date to a more readable format.

Javadoc for `Date()` constructor:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.

If you want to convert a formatted date back to a date object (so you can work with it) `DateFormat.parse(..)` can help you ;-)

Comment: great thanks, and what if I also want to include the time there, so it is actually like a datetime?